# how to use google cloud api in java with gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEvwN.png)

I was following the tutorial on the Google Cloud platform, but I do not get it at all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dLqH.png)

So I got a bulid file that did not exist, and I thought I could use the build / ilbs / name-jar file, but it did not.

When I ran build I saw a lot of downloads. Maybe download the api.

I created a different project and used a jar file, but I read the error "The import com.google can not be resolved" in every import com.google section

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgSFw.png)

I am not an English citizen. This article is written in Google Translator.
Sorry for the poor English.

I could not find a good example in my language.

Answer (score 0):

To have a complete set of configuration in a eclipse project you need the following configuration in the build.gradle file (see section "Installation is easy" in this [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)):

```
 repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
  }
```

You can add the [Speech API dependency](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library):

```
 compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.53.0-alpha'
```

In the images you attached, there are mixing eclipse projects: ttt and fairy. In the project fairy the build.gradle doesn't seem exist and this is a cause for the unknown com.google package.

Add the build.gradle or recreate the Gradle Project, then click Refresh Gradle Project.